# Problem displaying widgets / ipywidgets install unsuccessful

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I'm implementing widgets in my jupyter notebook (via anaconda). I tried first by using an old code from a professor of mine, but it's not displaying widgets.

I tried installing:

> jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager

But it was unsuccessful

This was presented when I attempted installation of the package via windows command prompt:

> C:\Users\davio>jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       from notebook.base.handlers import (   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       from tornado import web, gen, escape, httputil   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 87,
>   in 
>       from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       import ssl   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in 
>       import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could
>   not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-labextension-script.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from jupyterlab.labextensions import main   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from .commands import (   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       from jupyterlab_server.process import which, Process, WatchHelper   File
>   "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server__init__.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from .app import LabServerApp   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       from .server import ServerApp   File "C:\Users\davio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       from jupyter_server.base.handlers import (                          # noqa ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server'

I expect to:

i) Be able to install all the required ipy packages in order to display widgets properly

ii) View and manipulate widgets properly
Thank you!!!!

Comment: Plese make your question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you had alredy python installed before installing anaconda, that's the problem. Try uninstalling python and only working with anaconda's python, that worked for me.
(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Please, explain why your solution should be worked.

Comment: @hamedbaziyad It's a DLL problem: "DLL load failed", it's getting a conflict between python versions.