# Jupyter Lab issue displaying widgets (javascript error)

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, ipyvuetify

I have troubles replicating a JupyterLab install on a new PC. It is working fine on my previous one.
I am unable to display simple widgets (like a checkbox from ipywidgets or ipyvuetify).
I checked that jupyter-widgets is enabled with jupyter labextension list. The results is :

```
jupyter-vue v1.7.0 enabled ok
jupyter-vuetify v1.8.4 enabled ok
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v5.0.2 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
```

In the notebook, when i try to display a widget, the cell displays a Javascrip error :

```
[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Failed to load model class 'CheckboxModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls'
Error: Module @jupyter-widgets/controls, version ^1.5.0 is not registered, however, 2.0.0 is 
at f.loadClass (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-
manager/static/134.083e6b37f2f7b2f04b5e.js?v=083e6b37f2f7b2f04b5e:1:74976)
at f.loadModelClass (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab- 
manager/static/150.467514c324d2bcc23502.js?v=467514c324d2bcc23502:1:10721)
at f._make_model (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab- 
manager/static/150.467514c324d2bcc23502.js?v=467514c324d2bcc23502:1:7517)
at f.new_model (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab- 
manager/static/150.467514c324d2bcc23502.js?v=467514c324d2bcc23502:1:5137)
at f.handle_comm_open (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab- 
manager/static/150.467514c324d2bcc23502.js?v=467514c324d2bcc23502:1:3894)
at _handleCommOpen (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab- 
manager/static/134.083e6b37f2f7b2f04b5e.js?v=083e6b37f2f7b2f04b5e:1:73392)
at b._handleCommOpen (http://localhost:8888/static/lab/jlab_core.86360d749a1ef5f29afb.js? 
v=86360d749a1ef5f29afb:2:924842)
at async b._handleMessage 
(http://localhost:8888/static/lab/jlab_core.86360d749a1ef5f29afb.js? 
v=86360d749a1ef5f29afb:2:926832)
```

Comment: Always best if you supply more information, like the result of `!python -c "import sys; print('\n',sys.version); import ipympl; print('ipympl version:', ipympl.__version__)" && jupyter --version && jupyter nbextension list && jupyter labextension list`, yet I suspect you have the issue noted [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12977#issuecomment-1221309124) & so I think you want to change your ipywidgets version to 7.7.2 or 7.6.5 to fix this issue. Check [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3558#issuecomment-1221309944), too.

Comment: Alternatively, [this person posted code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60059786/8508004) suggesting how to control some versions when using conda and so adapting some of that might help if you are using the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: Thx a lot @Wayne, I change ipywidget version to 7.7.2 and it worked

Comment: Making sure the whole environment is up to date, is enough to avoid this problem, as in  this similar question: [Jupyter Notebook javascript error when trying to display the widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78223853/12846804)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That error is consistent with [one noted here in an issue report recently](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12977#issuecomment-1221309124). The suggestion there is to change to ipywidgets version 7.7.2 or 7.6.5 to fix this issue. Also, see the note [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3558#issuecomment-1221309944), too.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when my ipywidgets version is 7.6.5 After I updated ipywidgets version to 8.0.4, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar error message, enabling the relevant jupyter extension and restarting the kernel solved the problem.

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

You can find the detailed instructions [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/user_install.html)

Comment: it works, `!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it for me:

```
pip install -U ipywidgets
```

That command changed to these versions:

```
    Uninstalling ipywidgets-7.6.5:
      Successfully uninstalled ipywidgets-7.6.5
Successfully installed comm-0.2.1 ipywidgets-8.1.2 jupyterlab-widgets-3.0.10 widgetsnbextension-4.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when executing a notebook on *mybinder.com*. The *environment.yml* file contained:

channels:

- conda-forge

dependencies:

- python=3.8.8
- jupyter=1.0.0
- jupyterlab=3.0.14
- ipywidgets=7.5.1
- matplotlib=3.4.1
- numpy=1.20.2
- scipy=1.6.2
- pandas=1.2.4

Running

> pip install ipympl==0.9.3

or

> conda install ipympl=0.9.3

in *Terminal* or in *Console* solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment under Waynes answer but I can't so here it is.
I had the same problem with 8.0.6
I downgraded to 8.0.4 and then it worked!