# Jupyter Notebook javascript error when trying to display the widgets

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am currently working on a EDA Project using `ydata_profiling` library.

This is the code i have written as of now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

profile = ProfileReport(df, title='Pandas Profiling Report', explorative=True)

profile.to_widgets()
```

On displaying this `.to_widgets()` code, a summary of my data appears, but under the variables section i get this javascript error:

```
[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Model class 'AccordionModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls' is loaded but can not be instantiated
Error: widget model not found 
at f.get_model (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/336.0a90bd910629a565bb7e.js?v=0a90bd910629a565bb7e:1:3460)
    at P (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/595.998263bfa9875eeeb29b.js?v=998263bfa9875eeeb29b:1:6289)
    at Object.P [as deserialize] (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/595.998263bfa9875eeeb29b.js?v=998263bfa9875eeeb29b:1:6099)
    at kt._deserialize_state (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/595.998263bfa9875eeeb29b.js?v=998263bfa9875eeeb29b:1:12378)
    at f._make_model (http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/336.0a90bd910629a565bb7e.js?v=0a90bd910629a565bb7e:1:7932)
Report generated by YData.
```

I would really appreciate some suggestions or fixes for this.

Solution:
Please don't overlook updating the version of your jupyter notebook. I updated the entire jupyter notebook environment and reloaded and issue got resolved.
Run commands like :

```
jupyter notebook --version

pip install --upgrade notebook
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Lab issue displaying widgets (javascript error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73715821/jupyter-lab-issue-displaying-widgets-javascript-error). Looks like your problem has nothing to see with ydata_profiling but all with jupyter widgets.

Comment: My ipywidget Version: 7.8.1
should i update then ?
Also now my report is not being generated at all using pandas profiling..i think i ran some wrong commands. 
Please click on this link to see my problem, please help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78224554/jupyter-notebook-not-rendering-report-with-pandas-profiling

Comment: Thank You Oca! That link you happened to paste helped me

Comment: It just hepled me render the report again as i ran the command : ```pip install -U ipywidgets```

But im facing this error still which is different from that link as it says : Model class 'AccordionModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls' is loaded but can not be instantiated Error: widget model not found

Comment: So the error persists despite updating. What version of ipywidgets do you have now, and have you tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76946167/12846804 by Marcelo Lacerda

Comment: Yes! The version of ipywidgets now is : ```Name: ipywidgets
Version: 8.1.2.```
```On running this command :jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension```
```i got error as : Jupyter command `jupyter-nbextension` not found.```

Comment: Thank you so much Oca !!! Turns out it was a simple notebook update it needed. Very stupid mistake. But thankful for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jupyter Lab issue displaying widgets (javascript error)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73715821/12846804) received several relevant answers, none of them being a definite answer on its own. This suggests:

- that you should update ipywidgets because some versions have been reported to cause this issue, e.g. 7.7.2 (this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73733358/12846804)
- that this might also arise from outdated jupyter notebook version, as some versions require manual activation of widgets (this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76946167/12846804)

So, first step is **making sure the whole environment is up to date**, starting with conda, then Jupyter and ipywidgets.

---

A couple notes:

- Caution: Because you are using conda, do **stick to conda** and not mix in some **pip** commands, because those are not going to install things at the same location, so you're asking for trouble.
- Since you're updating, consider making the move from Jupyter to **JupyterLab**.