# Jupyter Notebook not rendering report with pandas profiling

Tags: python, widget, jupyter, ipywidgets, pandas-profiling

I am encountering an issue with generating report using Pandas Profiling library.
I have uninstalled and installed the library again in a newly created environment , still not able to generate any report.
Only now the table is displayed as shown in ss. Please help me fix it.

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport```

```from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes```

```diab_data=load_diabetes()```

```df=pd.DataFrame(data=diab_data.data,columns=diab_data.feature_names)```

```df.head()```
```### To Create the Simple report quickly
profile = ProfileReport(df, title='Pandas Profiling Report')```

```profile.to_widgets()```

I was expecting To see reports being generated and green progress bar but rather i see 0% rendering and tables. Please help me fix it.

No report is rendered using pandas profiling, i only see this piece of code : 

`Summarize dataset:           0%|          | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Generate report structure:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Render widgets:              0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]`


`Solution to rendering the report again:`
`pip install -U ipywidgets`
````

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please do it already this time, unless a picture is absolutely necessary, as you risk your post being closed upon review. This is how SO works.

Comment: How is this post related to your other post from today : https://stackoverflow.com/q/78223853/12846804 Is this part of the same problem?

Comment: Yes! It was a part of it.
I encountered that problem just today itself when the report atleast rendered itself but the variables section was showing javascript error in that generated report, so i posted that error. 
I tried fixing it but i think some error has occurred after running some commands and now the report won't even render itself. So hence i had to post this issue as well.

Comment: Do keep tag [python] instead of [data-science], which is mostly uninformative

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report")
profile.to_widgets()
```

without `explorative=True` parameter in the profileReport?

Comment: are all packages up to date? Does it work if you do report=profiler.get_description() and report.to_file('my_json.json')? It should save the report in a json file.

Comment: what about this: Does it work if you do report=profiler.get_description() and report.to_file('my_json.json')? It should save the report in a json file

Comment: i'm simply a user as you are, just trying to help. If I simply call the profiler (without any command) it is showed to me. It's not as pretty as "to_widgets", but it's fine.
I think it's a simple version problem if it doesn't work. I'm using
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-events==0.9.0
jupyter-lsp==2.2.2
jupyter_client==8.6.0
jupyter_core==5.5.0
jupyter_server==2.12.0
jupyter_server_terminals==0.4.4
jupyterlab==4.0.9
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.9
jupyterlab_pygments==0.3.0
jupyterlab_server==2.25.2
ydata-profiling==4.7.0
pandas==2.2.1
with python 3.9.13 on windows.

Comment: I ran this command and the report got rendered finally :
```pip install -U ipywidgets```

it indeeed was some version error